# Google Analytics Reporting v4 with streams instead of views

Tags: ruby, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-ruby-client

I've just created a new Google Analytics property and it now defaults to data streams instead of views.

I had some code that was fetching reports through the API that I now need to updated to work with those data streams instead of views since there are not views anymore.

I've looked in the [docs](https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-apis-analyticsreporting_v4/v0.13.0/Google/Apis/AnalyticsreportingV4/ReportRequest.html) but i don't see anything related to data streams, anybody knows how this is done now?

Here's my current code that works with a view ID (I'm using the ruby `google-api-client` gem):

```
    VIEW_ID = "XXXXXX"
    SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'

    client = AnalyticsReportingService.new

    #server to server auth mechanism using a service account
    @creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds({:json_key_io => File.open('account.json'), :scope => SCOPE})
    @creds.sub = "myserviceaccount@example.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    client.authorization = @creds

    #metrics
    metric_views = Metric.new
    metric_views.expression = "ga:pageviews"
    metric_unique_views = Metric.new
    metric_unique_views.expression = "ga:uniquePageviews"

    #dimensions
    dimension = Dimension.new
    dimension.name = "ga:hostname"

    #range
    range = DateRange.new
    range.start_date = start_date
    range.end_date = end_date

    #sort
    orderby = OrderBy.new
    orderby.field_name = "ga:pageviews"
    orderby.sort_order = 'DESCENDING'

    rr = ReportRequest.new
    rr.view_id = VIEW_ID
    rr.metrics = [metric_views, metric_unique_views]
    rr.dimensions = [dimension]
    rr.date_ranges = [range]
    rr.order_bys = [orderby]

    grr = GetReportsRequest.new
    grr.report_requests = [rr]

    response = client.batch_get_reports(grr)
```

I would expect that there would be a `stream_id` property on the `ReportRequest` object that I could use instead of the `view_id` but that's not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing code uses the Google Analytics Reporting api to extract data from a Universal analytics account.

Your new Google analytics property is a Google Analytics GA4 account. To extract data from that you need to use the [Google analytics data api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1)  These are two completely different systems.  You will not be able to just port it.

You can find info on the new api and new library here: [Ruby Client for the Google Analytics Data API](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/docs/reference/google-analytics-data/latest)

```
$ gem install google-analytics-data
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Linda's answer i was able to get it working, here's the same code ported to the data API, it might end up being useful to someone:

```
    client = Google::Analytics::Data.analytics_data do |config|
      config.credentials = "account.json"
    end

    metric_views = Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::Metric.new(name: "screenPageViews")
    metric_unique_views = Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::Metric.new(name: "totalUsers")
    dimension = Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::Dimension.new(name: "hostName")
    range = Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::DateRange.new(start_date: start_date, end_date: end_date)
    order_dim = Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::OrderBy::DimensionOrderBy.new(dimension_name: "screenPageViews")
    orderby = Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::OrderBy.new(desc: true, dimension: order_dim)

    request = Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::RunReportRequest.new(
      property: "properties/#{PROPERTY_ID}",
      metrics: [metric_views, metric_unique_views],
      dimensions: [dimension],
      date_ranges: [range],
      order_bys: [orderby]
    )

    response = client.run_report request
```